# Using optional multi-value textbox as dataset filter

Tags: reporting-services, optional-parameters

I have a report which returns list of product names and other product specs. This report currently has different search options. My users now also want to be able to search by product number by putting in multiple product numbers.

How can I add a filter by product number which is an optional multi-value textbox?
I have tried to add a multi-value textbox. The report doesn't seem to work when no values are entered. If I put one or more product number in the text box, it seems to work fine. Is there a way I can tell the report doesn't filter on the Null value parameters? Or any other idea to work with optional multi-value parameters?

Here is the setting for my multi-value textbox

```
    Name = ProductNumber
    Prompt = Product Number
    Data Type = Text
    Allow Blank Value (checked)
    Allow Null value (not checked)
    Allow Multiple Values (checked)
```

Here is the data set filter

```
    Expression = [ProductNumber]
    Operator = In
    Value = [@ProductNumber]
```

Thanks

TL

Comment: I'm not what the question is here... the way I read this, it seems like you've set up a multi-value parameter that is working correctly? You always have to select at least one value for a multi-value parameter. Can you please confirm what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Ian, what I try to achieve is to have an **optional** multi-value textbox (filter by product numbers) as one of the search criteria on my report. That means the users can decide to whether to put one or more product number to search or they can omit searching by product numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should trick the dataset filter by:

1. Expression should check to see if the parameter is blank and if so give expression a 1 else the field.
2. Value should do the same check and if parameter is blank set value to 1 else set it to the parameter.

But keep your operator.

---

Alternatively you could do this similarly in the SQL and with more flexibility and performance.

Comment: Thanks glh. Could you show me how to do the expression at the Value setting in dataset filter? Not sure if it is the report version (MS VS 2008, SQL 2008) I have. The Expression button is grayed out when the operator is "In".

Comment: Honestly, given the new information, based on the recent comments, doing this at the database level is going to be by far the easiest option if you can. So +1 for this option.

Answer (score 2):

So as you've seen in your own testing, at least one value must be selected with multi-value parameters. You can't set `Allow null value` to true at design time and if you run a report without selecting any values it will throw an error message.

So you can't really have a report where users can run it with no values selected.

Taking a step back, what you're trying to achieve when ignoring the parameter is to include all *Product Numbers* by default. So why don't you set the parameter to have a default value of all *Product Numbers* selected? That way, users can just ignore and leave them all ticked if they don't want to filter by *Product Numbers*. Seems like a good workaround to me.

To do this, set the default value for the parameter using the same dataset that populates it:

[image]

All *Product Numbers* are now selected and users only need to take action if they want a subset of these returned.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Ian. The problem I have with this is the textbox is not populated product numbers for users to check or uncheck. The textbox is a blank textbox which users can paste one or more product numbers (line by line) to it. The report will automatically put coma delimiter between them.